# Make list into symbol

Tags: list, lisp, elisp

I was trying to `pop` an element of a list in elisp as follows,

```
(pop '(1 2))
```

but, due to my misunderstanding, that doesn't work b/c the list hasn't been internalized as a symbol.  Is there an idiomatic way to do the above, or is that not a proper approach?  Messing around a bit further I found I could do

```
(pop (progn (setq tmp '(1 2)) tmp))
```

but it doesn't seem right.  Is there a way to make anonymous lists and modify them in place like I was trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_pop.htm) is a *macro*
which *modifies* the value of its argument,
a [place](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_a.htm).

E.g.,

```
(defparameter *var* '(1 2 3))
(pop *var*)
==> 1
*var*
==> (2 3)
```

Note that what gets modified is the value of the place, not the object contained in the place.

E.g.,

```
(defparameter *var-1* '(1 2 3))
(defparameter *var-2* *var-1*)
(pop *var-1*)
==> 1
*var-1*
==> (2 3)
*var-2*
==> (1 2 3)
```

IOW, the list `(1 2 3)` is not modified, only the value of the variable is.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`pop` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't modify any lists. It simply rebinds the given variable with the list's `cdr`.

Running `(macroexpand '(pop foo))` in Emacs, I get:

```
(car-safe (prog1 foo (setq foo (cdr foo))))
```

Notice the absence of any list-modification functions such as `rplaca` or `rplacd`.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Only the variable binding is mutated, not the actual object.